# Framebuffer size and viewport relationship

Tags: opengl, graphics, viewport, fbo

I am a bit confused about the relationship between the framebuffer and the viewport. I have an application that uses a main FBO of size screenWidth+1 and screenHeight. I've added one to the width cause its the only way I've found that really enables fullscreen in X11 (at least on the board we are using).

In any case I create the projection and camera matrices based on screenWidth & screenHeight (ignoring the +1). There is no other reference actually to this +1 in the application except for when we create the window and the main FBO. So all in all I expected it to work fine and just have an empty column of pixels at the end of my FBO.

The viewport I use is set as glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight). The y coordinate is 0 because my projection is flipped on the y axis. Its been like this for quite a while and (I thought) there were no artifacts due to that +1.

But I did a quick test and changed that +1 to +500 or some other big number and I noticed that some objects in the scene were shifted to the right. It appears that the padding in the FBO affects stuff.

Why would this be the case? From what I understand the viewport converts normalised device coordinates to window coordinates. So if I understand this correctly by using screenWidth and screenHeight for the viewport I should just be filling a screenWidth x screenHeight area in the FBO, excluding that extra pixel at the end.

Can someone shed some light on this? Would I have to change my viewport to fit the size of the FBO?

Comment: Since you will never see the data you rendered into an FBO, you must be doing _something_ so that it actually appears on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about needing an extra pixel for fullscreen rendering.

However, you are right in your comprehension of the viewport. It is used to map normalized device coordinates (-1 to +1) to pixel coordinates in the FBO's attachments. (-1, -1) in normalized device coordinate is the bottom-left corner of the viewport (x and y parameters of `glViewport()`). (+1, +1) is the top-right corner of the viewport. Therefore, the size in pixels of the rendered surface in the FBO will not change as you make the texture attachments larger.

After rendering, in order to actually display something you must have some operation to transfer the pixels from the rendered texture to your window's presentation space. This is usually the [default framebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Default_Framebuffer). Typically you will [blit](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer#Blitting) from your rendering FBO (which possibly has multisampling) to the default framebuffer. I would expect the problem to be in the blitting part for your rendering pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The problem was that I was using the padded size in my application including in the projection and camera matrix so everything was a bit messed up. I made sure I now ignore that extra pixel and use the proper size and it all looks ok. I'll mark this as an answer as it clarifies the relationship between viewport and color attachment of an FBO.